# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in Javascript math function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some Javascript code that will brute force a value in an algebra equation and return the correct answer to me.

The equation is "9^(x-1) / 27^(2x-1) = 1", where I'm supposed to find the value of x. I wrote the following Javascript to try and solve it, but when I enter it into the Chrome console, it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Here's the code I'm using.

```
for (i = -500; i < 500; i++) {
    if ( Math.pow(9, i-1) / Math.pow(27, 2i+1) == 1) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

How might I prevent the error from occurring?

Answer (score 2):

The error is `2i+1`, this is invalid syntax.

You can use `*` operator for multiplication.

```
2 * i + 1
```

Comment: I wanted to answer the same, but I found it intriguing that Firefox gave me a different error: _“SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal”_. Is it still caused by the same error?

Comment: @Xufox yes, that is the same error and it is descriptive too _identifier starts immediately after numeric literal_

Comment: @Xufox Chrome shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Yeah, but with _only_ something like `var i=0; 2i;`?

Comment: @Xufox Chrome thinks that `(27, 2` closing bracket should be here and remaining part is next statement, so shows the error like this

Comment: @ashfla That's because the `if` statement never returns truthy value and `console.log` is never executed

Comment: @Tushar So that would mean that the number I'm looking for isn't inside that number range?

Comment: @ashfla The condition `if ( Math.pow(9, i-1) / Math.pow(27, 2i+1) == 1) {` is never truthy

Comment: @Tushar No, that’s not what I meant. I mean, as a standalone piece of code, what `var i=0; 2i;` would yield. Anyway, it yields “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL”, which is _far less_ descriptive than the error message in Firefox…

Comment: @ashfla If your problem is solved kindly accept the answer